# Could not update data: Access denied for user 'xxxx'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so I have been trying to fix this issue for a few hours now and have had no luck. Hopefully one/some of you brilliant programmers can aid in getting this code working properly. Currently, I have two databases set up: Users and AvatarDB. In Users, I have a table called userinfo and in AvatarDB I have a table called Avatars. What I am trying to do is have Users upload an avatar which will be stored in the AvatarDB and will have the same ID as the user ID. (For simplicity and troubleshooting purposes, I am currently just asking the user to enter their ID into the form, however once I get this code working will then have the code retrieve their user ID from my Users database) Unfortunately, when I try to upload an avatar I get the error in the title. Here is my code for connecting to the database:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxx"; (I put the username here)
$password = "xxxx"; (I put the password here)

// Create connection
$db = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$db) { die("Connection failed: " . mysql_connect_error()); }
```

Then, my upload.php file is as follows:

```
<?PHP include(connect.php) ?>

<form id="avatar" name="avatar" method="post" action="submitAvatar.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

ID:
<input type="text" id="memberId" name="memberId">

Upload Avatar:
<input type="file" onchange="load_image(this.id,this.value);" id="userAvatar" name="userAvatar"> 

<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Update Avatar" id="updateAvatar" name="updateAvatar">

</form>
```

My submitAvatar.php is as follows:

```
<?PHP include(connect.php);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && $_POST['updateAvatar'] == 'Update Avatar') {
    if($_POST['memberId']=="") {
        echo "Member id is required";
    } else {

        $memberId = $_POST['memberId'];
        $updtDate = date("Y-m-d : H:i:s", time());
        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "bmp");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["userAvatar"]["name"]);

        if($_FILES['userAvatar']['size']>0) {
            if (in_array(strtolower($temp[1]), $allowedExts)) {

                $picNm = uniqid().".jpg";
                $path="memberAvatars/".$picNm;

                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userAvatar']['tmp_name'],$path)) {

                    $sql = "UPDATE Avatars ". "SET name = $picNm ". "WHERE memberId = $memberId" ;
                    mysql_select_db('AvatarDB');
                    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $db );
                    if(! $retval ) { die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error()); }
                    echo "Updated data successfully\n";
                    mysql_close($db);
                } else {
                    echo "Error1.";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Invalid type.";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Anyone have any idea why I'm getting the following error?

> Could not update data: Access denied for user 'xxxx'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could it be that the database is denying access for the user/password combination you're using?

Comment: I think the problem is not in code. The error said he does not use password, but in fact he enters password in `mysql_connect()`... hey, stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions! use PDO / MySQLi instead.

Comment: @MikeW I don't think so, since it is allowing me to connect to the database in connect.php

Comment: and use lowercase `<?php` please, though you are legal to use uppercase.

Comment: @jrt18 Ahh - so when it says 'Access denied' it's not being entirely truthful? There's something wrong with the credentials you're using. Start there.

Comment: @MikeW I wish it were that simple, however there are no other credentials for the database. The username and password combination I am using is the only possible option, and work with connecting to the database in other ways. For instance, I used connect.php and I was able to retrieve the information from Avatars.

Comment: @Raptor I have tried using PDO but found it gave me the same error

Comment: Of course PDO won't solve the problem. **the problem is elsewhere**. You may think we're not helping you, but you can debug yourself more thoroughly. In your `connect.php`, `$db` is initialized successfully. Try to `var_dump` it before query.

Comment: First; using two separate databases for this is going to cause nothing but pain. Use one database with two tables. Second; my best guess is you have more than one `connect.php` file and your `submitAvatar.php` script is using the wrong one (the one with an empty password and no connection error checking).

Answer (score 0):

Here are my ideas on this issue. No need to put `<?PHP include(connect.php) ?>` in `upload.php` unless your actually doing a query there which it doesn't look like. It's already included in `submitAvatar.php`.

I believe the issue is in the syntax of your query or the way you have included your connection script. You may need to use quotes inside your include.

```
<?PHP include('connect.php') ?>
```

Also, try changing

```
$sql = "UPDATE Avatars ". "SET name = $picNm ". "WHERE memberId = $memberId" ;
```

to

```
$sql = "UPDATE Avatars SET name = $picNm WHERE memberId = $memberId";
```

Alternatively, if you want it quoted, the correct format would be.

```
$sql = "UPDATE Avatars SET name = '".$picNm."' WHERE memberId = '".$memberId"'";
```

**EDIT:**

After looking more closely at your code, I believe the problem lies here:

```
mysql_select_db('AvatarDB');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $db );
```

Looks like you've got them switched, try

```
mysql_select_db('AvatarDB', $db);
$retval = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Whilst the query string concatenation there is bizarre, it's not the cause of that specific error, nor is your string any different in the end.

Comment: The error itself as bizarre as well. Which makes me think it will take something unorthodox to fix it.